# Canon MF8000C series won't print

Tags: printing, canon

I have two machines in red one with Ubuntu 17.04 and it works without problem but with the one that has the Ubuntu 17.10 version I can not install it even though I do the same installation under the disk drive and I run the install.sh I do not know what to do. help?

```
lpstat -t
el planificador de tareas se está ejecutando
no hay un destino predeterminado del sistema
dispositivo para Canon_MF8000C_Series: dnssd://Canon%20MF8000C%20Series._pdl-datastream._tcp.local/
dispositivo para CUPS-BRF-Printer: cups-brf:/
Canon_MF8000C_Series aceptando peticiones desde sáb 10 feb 2018 12:33:57 -04
CUPS-BRF-Printer aceptando peticiones desde sáb 10 feb 2018 12:31:19 -04
la impresora Canon_MF8000C_Series está inactiva.  activada desde sáb 10 feb 2018 12:33:57 -04
la impresora CUPS-BRF-Printer está inactiva.  activada desde sáb 10 feb 2018 12:31:19 -04
```

Comment: there are many reports that 17.10 does not work with the Canon drivers; ( I assume you are using the UFR3.4 driver that came out in Nov 2017;) so UFR is fine with 17.04; Canon are working on a new driver; 17.10 was a big leap into somewhere and there are scanner issues too; hopefully 18.04 as an LTS will be more stable

Answer (score 1):

Canon released on 8th Feb 2018 a 3.5 version of the driver; that I understand has been tested on Ubuntu 17.10 and works! and I wonder if you see this answer if you download and install it.

you can get it from here http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/contents/ASIA/EN/0100924010.html and it comes down as linux-UFRII-drv-v350-uken.tar.gz so the commands to install should be

```
cd Downloads
tar -zxvf linux-UFRII-drv-v350-uken.tar.gz
cd linux-UFRII-drv-v350-uken
sudo ./install.sh
```

you might like to go into synaptic and delete the existing packages for 3.4 which seem to be cndrvcups-common_3.80-1_amd64.deb and cndrvcups-ufr2-uk_3.40-1_amd64.deb

Comment: Thank you very much, with this solve the problem of the printer

Comment: glad it all works and hopefully Canon's new driver will be good for 18.04; they were able to download beta versions in Feb

Answer (score 0):

I had problems getting my MF8580cdw to print, but those went away when I actually used the install.sh script file to install the drivers, etc. I believe the install.sh scripts install the necessary files if it doesn't find them on your computer. It installed a lot of files, even after I had previously intalled the .deb driver files.